# Can't change the same HTML tag styles for each React Component

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to change the background of the body tag for each component of my page, but if I declare the background the each component css file it causes conflict.

Component 1 css file:

```
body {  
   background: url('../../assets/img/Forma_1.svg') left top no-repeat, 
   url('../../assets/img/Forma_2.svg') right 30% no-repeat, var(--blue);
   background-size: 295px, 64px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   body {
     background: url('../../assets/img/Forma_1.svg') left top no-repeat, 
     url('../../assets/img/Forma_2.svg') right center no-repeat, var(--blue);
     background-size: 395px, 104px;
  }
}
```

Component 2 css file: (the styles of this file apply to all the pages because of the !important, but if I take out the styles of the first file apply on the Component 2)

```
body {
  background: url('../../assets/img/Forma_1.svg') left top no-repeat, 
  url('../../assets/img/Forma_2_flip.svg') left center no-repeat, #fff !important;
  background-size: 295px, 64px !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: url('../../assets/img/Forma_1.svg') left top no-repeat, 
    url('../../assets/img/Forma_2.svg') right center no-repeat, 
    url('../../assets/img/Patas.png') right top no-repeat, #fff !important;
    background-size: 395px, 104px, 147px !important;
 }
```

}

Comment: Can you have one globally included CSS file that contains multiple classes for body (e.g. `body.light { background: #fff; }` ) and then, in your components, reference the appropriate class name?

Comment: I could but I doesn't have a body tag on my components, the style change only the main body tag, it's strange because seens like my .css files are been carred over to other compents, so my compoent1.css is applyed on my Component2. I'm using React Router and I don't know if that has something to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing what your components look like, but here are some of the possible issues I can think of:

1. You are trying to render multiple `<body>` elements. This will
   not work because HTML expects only one `<body>` --> use `<div className="class">`
   and add CSS for the class instead.
2. You are importing both CSS files into both of your component files. Try importing only the CSS you want to use for that component

Comment: My components doesn't have <body> tags, I'm trying to change the main <body> tag, and the styles are in different .css files, seens like when I change the page the CSS stays applied, I'm using React Router and I don't know if it has something to do with it

Comment: If your components are wrapped inside a <body>, then <body> will always render first, using whichever CSS file(s) you used when declaring the <body>. I would recommend you style the background of each component individually instead of styling <body>.